# JavaFX HMTLEditor doesn't react on 'return' key

Tags: java, javafx-2

I was trying to do some experiments with JavaFX' `HTMLEditor` component. I used the following code(excerpt):

```
    fxPanel=new JFXPanel();
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Group group = new Group();
            scene = new Scene(group);               
            fxPanel.setScene(scene);
            view = VBoxBuilder.create().build();

            group.getChildren().add(view);


            edit = HTMLEditorBuilder.create().build();
           // toolPane = TabPaneBuilder.create().minHeight(60d).build();
            //toolPane.getTabs().add(new Tab("Allgemein"));

            view.getChildren().add(edit);

        }
    });

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            jPanel1.add(fxPanel);
        }
    });
```

It works fine so far with one important exception - i can't use the return key for a BR - it seems just to be ignored. There is no reaction on this key at all. As far as i could see, any other key works as expected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I noticed that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> works where <kbd>Enter</kbd> doesn't. So I just worked around this by putting a `KeyListener` on the JFXPanel, changing the `KeyChar` from 10 to 13 and reposting the event to the System Event Queue. This may stop working as intended later on if the HTMLEditor starts responding to both <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> though.

```
fxPanel.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyChar() == 10) {
            e.setKeyChar((char) 13);
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(e);
        }
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
});
```

Anyone have a better idea for now?

*Edit*: I found another way to get the desired effect is to install a custom `KeyEventDispatcher` on the current keyboard focus manager like so:

```
KeyboardFocusManager kfm = DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
kfm.addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        if (DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner() == jfxPanel) {
            if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED && e.getKeyChar() == 10) {
                e.setKeyChar((char) 13);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

This has the advantage of changing the original `KeyEvent` rather than posting a new one afterwards, so that if `HTMLEditor` were to start responding to <kbd>Enter</kbd> events we wouldn't be doubling up.

Comment: Of course `SHIFT`-`Enter` now inserts <br/> **and** a new paragraph... still this is a lot better than not being able to use `Enter` at all :)

Answer (score 4):

I found out that it's an already known bug in JavaFX.

https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-33354
and
http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-20887

But FYI, it was resolved as "Won't Fix" for JavaFX 2.2. There is no problem in JavaFX 8.

Answer (score 1):

I still see this problem with Oracle JDK 10. Peeking into the `HTMLEditorSkin`, there is a `Command.INSERT_NEW_LINE`, but it is not performed when pressing 'Enter'.
In principle, there is API for executing a `Command`, and that could be invoked from a key event filter, but the API is private.

The following is a hack around this limitation.
It "works", but it is of course a hack that might break with future updates of JavaFX:

```
HTMLEditor editor = /* .. somehow get the HTMLEditor .. */
editor.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event ->
{
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER)
    {
        event.consume();
        final HTMLEditorSkin skin = (HTMLEditorSkin) htmlEditor.getSkin();
        try
        {
            // Use reflection to invoke the private method
            // executeCommand(Command.INSERT_NEW_LINE.getCommand(), null);
            final Method method = skin.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("executeCommand", String.class, String.class);
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(skin, Command.INSERT_NEW_LINE.getCommand(), null);
        }
        catch (Throwable ex)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot hack around ENTER", ex);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can generate a line feed by filtering  events and firing a <^m> events to the webview instead

```
        // fix enter ignored on linux
    HTMLEditor editor = ...
    WebView editorView = (WebView) editor.lookup(".web-view");
    editor.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
            e.consume();
            editorView.fireEvent(new KeyEvent(
                    e.getSource(),
                    editorView,
                    KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED,
                    "\r", "", KeyCode.ENTER,
                    false, true, false, false));
        }
    });
```