# Entering new line in HTMLEditor in Java/JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, newline, html-editor

I have a problem with HTMLEditor used in JPanel. Everything is working fine, but going to new line by pressing ENTER doesn't work.

My code:

```
public class MessageEditor extends JPanel {

    private HTMLEditor htmlEditor;
    private Scene scene;
    private JFXPanel jfxPanel;

    public MessageEditor() {

        jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        loadJavaFXScene();
    }

    private void loadJavaFXScene() {

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                htmlEditor = new HTMLEditor();
                scene = new Scene(htmlEditor, 450, 450);
                scene.setRoot(htmlEditor);
                htmlEditor.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                        logger.debug("KE: " + event);


                jfxPanel.setScene(scene);

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        add(jfxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                        revalidate();
                        repaint();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

EventHandler handles ENTER key, but editor doesn't put new line.

```
KeyEvent [source = HTMLEditor[id=null, styleClass=root], target = WebView@e9bb131[styleClass=web-view], eventType = KEY_PRESSED, consumed = false, character = , code = ENTER]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaFX HMTLEditor doesn't react on 'return' key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269632/javafx-hmtleditor-doesnt-react-on-return-key)