# HTML textarea doesn't recognize the "enter" key as newline in WebView

Tags: java, textarea, javafx, enter

I have this code that simply loads an `HTML` file to a JavaFX `javafx.scene.web.WebView` from resources:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test extends Application {

    JFXPanel panel;
    JFrame frame;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                frame = new JFrame("Test");

                WebView v = new WebView();
                v.getEngine().load(getClass().getResource("htmlfile.html").toExternalForm());

                StackPane root = new StackPane();
                root.getChildren().add(v);
                Scene scene = new Scene(root);

                panel = new JFXPanel();
                panel.setScene(scene);
                panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(641, 725));

                frame.setContentPane(panel);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * main method
     *
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

`htmlfile.html` is this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

Everything is displayed correctly, the only problem is that if i type something in the textarea displayed in the `WebView` it doesn't recognize the `ENTER` key as a newline character. So in fact what it happens is that when i press `ENTER`, the `textarea` does nothing. Now, if you try the HTML above in a browser (like chrome or firefox) it will work.

Why is this happening?

How can i solve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaFX HMTLEditor doesn't react on 'return' key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269632/javafx-hmtleditor-doesnt-react-on-return-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had this exact same problem at my work in a Swing application using a JavaFX `HTMLEditor` (which internally uses a `WebView`).

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574495/195912) helped me workaround the problem. As the other answer saids, it's a known bug in JavaFX.

Comment: Oh, i see... I'm testing right now. Can you explain why everything works perfectly if i use the `primaryStage` instead of a `JFrame` with `JFXPanel`?

Comment: Nope not really. Probably some interoperability issue between Swing and JavaFX.